# How do i make something random in a function?

Tags: javascript, function, random

I have a function with some images in it here:

```
function rain() {
    ctx.drawImage (image1, x, y, 100, 50);
    ctx.drawImage (image2, x, y, 100, 50);
    ctx.drawImage (image3, x, y, 100, 50);
    ctx.drawImage (image4, x, y, 100, 50);
}
```

How do I make this function randomly choose one of these images when I call it?

Comment: [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your images in an array, then pick a random index of the array.

```js
function randomImage() {
  const images = [
    image1,
    image2,
    image3,
    image4,
  ];
  // Pick an index at random from the images array. Math.rand returns
  // a random number between 0 and 1, multiplying that by the length
  // of the images array, gets a number between 0 and the length of the
  // array, and flooring it makes it into an integer.
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.rand() * images.length);
  return images[randomIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's inconvenient to do math when I want to deal with randomness, so I use [Rando.js](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js) to make stuff like this simple and readable.

```js
var images = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

console.log( rando(images).value );
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

If you want to use this code, all you need to know is that the `script` tag sources in the `rando` function, and you're ready to use it right away. Just put the script tag in the head of your HTML document. It's easy, but if you need to know more, you can check out examples on the [website](https://randojs.com) or [github repo](https://github.com/nastyox/Rando.js).

Comment: Or instead of importing a third party script for that, you can simply build your own... `const rando = arr => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]`

Comment: yep, you totally can, but the other answer already sort of addressed that approach so i figured I'd add something new. it's definitely not an essential library, but it's a nice convenience to not have to think about the math. plus, it's super small (2.1kb) anyway, and it handles every type of value plus jquery elements to do pretty much anything you need. if you want to keep things local, you can always just copy the script directly from https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js into your project. It's kind of a preference thing. Some people like to see the math behind what they're doing, some people don't